# Is there a natural family of nonisomorphic groups parametrized by $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: group-theory

It's easy to construct a countable series of distinct groups - the cyclic groups, for instance - and it's also easy to create a family of groups parametrized by the reals, but most such constructions will have isomorphisms betwteen most if not all of the groups.

As the category Group is very large, one would expect that somewhere inside it lies a continuum-sized collection of groups which can be parametrized in some natural way and are all distinct, that is, nonisomorphic. However, I've pondered this for a bit and asked some friends and haven't come up with any clear constructions. So I'm curious if anyone can provide a collection of groups which is "natural" in some sense (ideally continuous, and not a composition of a bijection from a set of groups to $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ and from there to $\mathbb{R}$), continuum-sized, and whose elements are not isomorphic.

(Answers which provide a family parametrized by the nonnegative reals, or the positive reals, or the interval $[0,1]$, would also suffice.)

Comment: Not a "natural" example, but: there exist groups of any nonzero cardinality, and there are more cardinal numbers than there are elements of any set.  So for any set, you can find a family of groups parametrized by it which all have distinct cardinality and thus are not isomorphic.

Comment: There are nontrivial families of pairwise non-isomorphic nilpotent Lie groups of dimension 7 (or so).

Comment: These families are continuum-sized? If so, I'd love a pointer to more information about them (or relevant search terms)!

Comment: Relevant search terms are "classification nilpotent Lie algebras". Note that these are non-isomorphic as Lie groups a priori. Classification as abstract groups is probably unknown in these case (nor in the simpler examples 3-dimensional solvable examples I gave as an answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As proved in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3831720/are-these-permutation-groups-defined-by-asymptotic-properties-isomorphic?noredirect=1&lq=1) question, the groups $G_{x^r}$ for $r\in (0,1]$ (defined as permutations of $\mathbb{N}$ that fix all but  $o(n^r)$ elements) are pairwise non-isomorphic.

Answer (score 6):

For $s\in\mathbf{R}$ consider the group $G_s$ of matrices
$$\begin{pmatrix}e^t & 0 & x\\ 0 & e^{st} & y\\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}: \quad x,y,t\in\mathbf{R}.$$

This is a 3-dimensional connected Lie group. Then $G_s$ and $G_t$ are isomorphic Lie groups if and only if $st=1$ (exercise). Hence for $s>1$ they're pairwise non-isomorphic.